# The use of causative + もらう + なさい together

Tags: sentence, causation, giving-and-receiving

[image]

My understanding of the sentence is akin to  "Because there in no room for you, for a while make use of Ryo's room."

However, I don't understand this use of causative + もらう. Why add なさい?

Answer (score 3):

It's もらいな which is a rather more casual command than もらいなさい

If it were just 寝かせな the sentence would be confusing. 'There's no room for you, so get [someone else] to sleep in Rio's room for a while.' The room is for アンタ, and now it's going to someone else?

Rio is the one 寝かせるing アンタ. アンタ needs to get Rio to do this, so アンタ's action is 寝かせてもらう. The speaker is telling アンタ to get Rio to let them sleep in Rio's room, so of course, 寝かせてもらいな.

'We don't have a room for you so get Rio to let you sleep in their room'